# Specific package name encoding in gradle script in android?

Tags: android, gradle

i am trying to apply compile option encoding based on package name in gradle script. I tried a lot, but i could not getting some idea. Can you please help me to solve this. Here is my target which i want to like compile through gradle.

```
def appId = 'com.example.one'
def appId2 = 'com.example.two'
if(appId && appId2){
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
}else{
    compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

I dont want to change manually in File->Settings->File encoding-> default encode. Please help!